OpenGL Error: Pixel Format is Invalid with ImGui-SFML in VS Code
So, I'm trying to get better at manually compiling and building a program in VS Code. Also I'm running Windows 11 22H2 if that helps. I'm using SFML and ImGui with the ImGui-SFML backend. After days of trying to get a program up and running, I managed to get an SFML window created with a green circle in it. I then integrated ImGui and ImGui-SFML compiled into an .exe but when I run the exe, I get a shit ton of errors saying about how the Pixel Format is Invalid.
this is my main.cpp, its just the example code from the ImGui-SFML repo:
#include "src/imgui-include/imgui.h"
#include "src/imgui-include/imgui-SFML.h"

#include <SFML/Graphics/CircleShape.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/RenderWindow.hpp>
#include <SFML/System/Clock.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window/Event.hpp>

int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "ImGui + SFML = <3");
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);
    ImGui::SFML::Init(window);

    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    sf::Clock deltaClock;
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            ImGui::SFML::ProcessEvent(window, event);

            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        ImGui::SFML::Update(window, deltaClock.restart());

        ImGui::ShowDemoWindow();

        ImGui::Begin("Hello, world!");
        ImGui::Button("Look at this pretty button");
        ImGui::End();

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        ImGui::SFML::Render(window);
        window.display();
    }

    ImGui::SFML::Shutdown();
}

This is the Makefile I have setup:
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -g -Wextra -Wall
INCLUDE = -Isrc/include -Isrc/imgui-include 
LIB = -Lsrc/lib -lsfml-audio -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-network -lsfml-system -lsfml-window -lopengl32

IMGUI_FILES = src/imgui-include/imgui.cpp src/imgui-include/imgui_draw.cpp src/imgui-include/imgui_widgets.cpp src/imgui-include/imgui_demo.cpp src/imgui-include/imgui_tables.cpp
IMGUI_SFML_FILES = src/imgui-include/imgui-SFML.cpp

all: compile link

compile:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(IMGUI_FILES) $(IMGUI_SFML_FILES) main.cpp $(INCLUDE)

link:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(IMGUI_FILES) $(IMGUI_SFML_FILES) main.o -o main $(LIB)


clean:
    del *.o *.exe

This is my settings.json:
{
    "cmake.configureOnOpen": true,
    "cmake.showOptionsMovedNotification": false,
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "makefile.makefilePath": "C:/Users/Peyton/source/repos/FortEditor/Makefile",
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "C_Cpp.default.compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
    "C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "${workspaceFolder}/src/**"
    ]
}

and this is my terminal output:
Failed to activate OpenGL context: The pixel format is invalid.
Failed to activate the window's context
Failed to activate OpenGL context: The pixel format is invalid. 
Failed to activate OpenGL context: The handle is invalid. 
Failed to activate OpenGL context: The handle is invalid.

I've alread tried to get everything linked and workinng, I have opengl32.dll in with the rest of the dll's.



What I was expecting was a window to be created with a green circle in it and for an ImGui Demo Window to be created. Like I said before, I had managed to get a working SFML window to appear with a green circle inside it using the example code from the Linux setup.

Where did you get SFML? Did you build it yourself?

No, I didn't think about that. I just added the inlcudes and libs. Maybe I should have done that.

Building it yourself is not necessarily better. So where did you get it?

I downloaded the GCC 13.1.0 MinGW (SEH) - 64-bit from the official website here: https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.6.1/

You will have to step through the ImGui-SFML code with a debugger to at least isolate the lines that raise these pixel format errors.
